# How to correctly insert a record with python flask to mysql (Error: 1045 using password: NO))

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am trying to insert a record from python using flask but when filling out the form and sending it to the function (def agrega) send me error:

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'Artron' @ 'localhost' (using password: NO) ")
```

I do not know why (the user has password correct and all their privileges).

My code :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL 
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MySQL_HOST']='localhost'
app.config['MySQL_USER']='arturo'
app.config['MySQL_PASSWORD']='Oro_2019'
app.config['MySQL_DB']='programas'
mysql = MySQL(app)
@app.route('/')
def Index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/add_contact', methods=['POST'])
def agrega():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        categoria = request.form['categoria']
        nombre = request.form['nombre']
        direccion = request.form['direccion']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO prog (categoria,nombre,direccion)VALUES (%s,%s,%s)',
        (categoria,nombre,direccion))
        mysql.connection.commit
        return 'received'
@app.route('/edit')
def edita():
    return 'Editar Contacto'
@app.route('/delete')
def elimina():
    return ("Elimina Contacto")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port = 3000, debug = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you are running a mysql workbench as well with the server?
if so login into the database with Arturo and the password - you might encounter an error here (which will mean you did not grant the rights correctly).

Also try the password without the capital O

If you manage to login run this:

```
SHOW GRANTS;
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;
```

and send us the results.

ALSO NEVER USE the actual credentials here just for safety reasons and good practice

Comment: Thanks for your response, the result, after applying SHOW GRANTS was:  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'arturo'@'localhost...
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `arturo`.* TO 'arturo'@'lo...
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `arturo\_%`.* TO 'arturo'@...
  and the same when applying SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT USER